# Modifiable Array of strings in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql

I am looking to store an Array of strings in a table which I can then append more data to.

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id SERIAL, username varchar(32), password char(40), name varchar(64), age integer, successful_logins varchar(32)[10], failed_logins varchar(32)[10], roles text[3]);
```

I have tried this but it doesnt do anything:

```
UPDATE users SET successful_logins = array_append(successful_logins, :timestamp) WHERE username = :username;
```

The `:varname` comes from a JDBI Driver I am using, but I am passing in a String. Why doesnt this work? Is there a better way to get the same result?

EDIT:

Here is the driver I am using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

I get no error and it seems to be releted to my DAO or driver.
Here is the DAO code:

```
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.Bind;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlUpdate;

@SqlUpdate("UPDATE users SET successful_logins=ARRAY_APPEND((SELECT successful_logins FROM users WHERE username=:username),:timestamp)WHERE username=:username")
void addSuccessfulLogin(@Bind("timestamp") String timestamp, @Bind("username") String username);
```

When I try this in `psql` with the vars replaces with values it works. I am wondering if this this a casting issue? Do I need to cast my String to something?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Do you get an error? If so, show it to us *(edit question)*. If no error, does the statement return an update count of 1?

Comment: @Andreas I have updated my answer with some information. I am using a DAO to write to the DB, I have included the code above. I get no error in my program, there may be an error in the psql logs? Do you know where they are?

Comment: Well, it looks like you're missing a space between ARRAY_APPEND() and WHERE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was making the call to `addSuccessfulLogin` I was doing:

```
addSuccessfulLogin(username, timestamp);
```

instead of

```
addSuccessfulLogin(timestamp, username)
```

So it was trying to find a username based on a timestamp, which doesnt exist. This is why there were no errors. SO make sure you call your own API correctly!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with your JDBI library, but I tried this in the Postgres console and it worked:

```
UPDATE mytable SET successful_logins = 
ARRAY_APPEND(
    (
     SELECT successful_logins FROM mytable WHERE id=1), 
    'Some additional value'
     ) 
WHERE id=1
```

Perhaps the problem is that you need to select the existing `successful_logins` value before you pass it to the `array_append`.

EDIT: Well, it looks like you're missing a space between ARRAY_APPEND() and WHERE...

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This works when im using `psql`, though I am currently using a DAO. I have updated my Question with some more information.

Comment: Added a space, didnt help. I have the log file now, but it only shows the errors that I get in my console, so its not much help.

Comment: Hmm...the only other things that come to mind are that perhaps your `username` doesn't exist, so no rows meet the `WHERE` condition, or that it violates the 32-character limit in the definition.  Or, perhaps your username has leading or trailing whitespace either in the DB or in the parameter you're passing?  Weird.

Comment: That was why I asked in a [question comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576281#comment68388739_40576281) whether the statement return an update count of 1. OP didn't bother to answer, perhaps because (s)he's unaware of how to get the update count. According to the [documentation](http://jdbi.org/sql_object_api_dml/), changing the return type to `int` will make it return the update count, and perhaps that will show whether the row is updated without doing anything (seems unlikely), or whether the `WHERE` clause fails and no rows are updated, giving credence to your comment.